# Server-Clients Caching

Tags: caching, drupal-7, browser-cache

In a Server-Client setting, when the Server sends page with Expiration of 2 days to the Client, am I correct that until 2 days after the Client receives the server response, Client will load the cached page?

The real question: The page in the Client is not yet Expired, can the Server push the Client to check for a modified copy of the page?

I want the clients to request only if there pages expire, or if the server pushes them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I can make of http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt, yes that is the intention of the Expiration control - a level of "staleness" of a page that is acceptable to use for offline browsing or in cases of poor network response.

Section 14.9.4 does state how the Client and Cache should behave on receiving a must-revalidate directive. This doesn't force the client to download, just to check the last-modified date with the server, which is what I think you require.

In IIS the directive is

```
<% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```

which you can read more about on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067. They talk about disabling the cache, but that defeats the purpose and decreases efficiency.

In PHP the directive is

```
header ("cache-control: must-revalidate");
```